# how to fix VBoxClient --clipboard ,it doesn't work and there is no process VBoxClient --clipboard so that i can't paste and copy to host-machine

Tags: virtualbox, clipboard

env: 
   vm ubuntu16.04

virtualbox

host-machine window 10

VBoxClient installed

problem: 
   when i run `ps -ef | grep VBox*`

there is no process VBoxClient --clipboard

but have process VBoxClient --seamless,  VboxClient --display

i try to run `/usr/bin/VBoxClient --clipboard` , `reboot` , `VBoxClient-all`  but it doesn't work how could i fix it , i don't want to reconfig another vm just for copy and paste

Comment: this problem is strange,  when i roll back the virtual-machine  to the initial state , the clipboard is fine. But along with my useage ,the virtual-machine size is getting bigger, then the clipboard is broken down.  So i will roll back my virtual-machine to the initial state.